# Java JAX-RS custom parameter with default value

Tags: java, jax-ws, resteasy

Let's say I have this (this is just a sample):

```
@GET
@Path(value="address")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getAddress(@QueryParam("user") User user){
  ...
}
```

and User is

```
class User{
...
 public static User valueOf(String user){
   if(user == null) return DEFAULT_USER;
   return dao.findById(user);
 }    
}
```

If I do **/api/address?user=amir** everything works but the idea is if I don't provide a value for user then I want DEFAULT_USER to be used. But this doesn't actually call valueOf. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Based on the code you provide and the docs for "DefaultValue", if the user is not present on the URL, it is assigned to null. You give the impression though that you expect the valueOf method to be called with parameter (String) null, which is not the way the omission of "DefaultValue" works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JAX-RS has the @[DefaultValue](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) annotation:

```
@QueryParam("user") @DefaultValue("__DEFAULT")



class User{
...
 public static User valueOf(String user){
   if(user == null||"__DEFAULT".equals(user) return DEFAULT_USER;
   return dao.findById(user);
 }    
}
```

Comment: How does this help me? If user is missing then I want DEFAULT_USER. Your code makes default use "amir"

Comment: that's what I am doing right now. I was hoping for a better solution. But I guess this will do.