# @DefaultValue for a list

Tags: java, jax-rs

In JAX-RS, I can define a query parameter to populate a list:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/foo")
 public String myService(
      @DefaultValue("default") @QueryParam("p") List<String> items
 ) {
     return items.toString();
 }
```

For a request like `.../foo?p=1&p=2`, items is `["1","2"]`.

`@DefaultValue` sets a default, but this always creates a collection with a single entry containing that default: for a request like `.../foo`, items is `["default"]`.

I would like a default which contains two entries. A fantasy approach that doesn't work is:

```
 @DefaultValue("foo","bar") List<String> items
```

The working code I have instead omits DefaultValue and instead has:

```
 if(items.isEmpty()) {
      items = asList("foo","bar");
 }
```

Is there a clean JAX-RS way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: The javadoc of `@Default` states the following: If the type of the annotated parameter is List, Set or SortedSet then the resulting collection will have a single entry mapped from the supplied default value. Given that it doesn't seem to be possible. Within the following answer a alternative is proposed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641778/java-jax-rs-custom-parameter-with-default-value.

Comment: Sorry missed the fact that you already noted it within your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey : Is it possible to specify multiple values in @DefaultValue() annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651066/jersey-is-it-possible-to-specify-multiple-values-in-defaultvalue-annotation)

Answer (score 1):

Might be too simplistic but a possible way to pass multiple default values for a list could be as follows:

```
public void dummy(@DefaultValue("foo,bar") String items) {
    List<String> parameters = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(",").split(items));
    ....
}
```

Comment: Considered this, but standards-minded HTTP people seem to prefer `?parm=foo&?parm=bar` to `?parms=foo,bar`

Comment: A way to comply to this might be that the `@DefaultValue` for example contains a unique prefix, and that we check whether that prefix is within the string if list is 1, so for example: `@DefaultValue("DefaultValues:foo,bar") List<String>  items` and then within the body we first check whether number of items = 1, and if so check whether the string starts with prefix `DefaultValue:`, and if so take the rest and transforms it into a list. Feels like a 'hacky' solution but might be a way.